# How to apply CSS to all pages except certain product pages in Wordpress/Woocommerce?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to know how to apply this CSS code to every page on my website except for woocommerce products with a category of 'Category1'.

```css
.custom-single-product .cart, span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount, a.cart-customlocation.et-cart-info {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I have tried adding a category class to the  tag with php using the code below but I have been unsuccessful in having it work for what I want.

```
// add taxonomy term to body_class
function woo_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class( $classes ){
  if( is_singular( 'product' ) )
  {
    $custom_terms = get_the_terms(0, 'product_cat');
    if ($custom_terms) {
      foreach ($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
        $classes[] = 'product_cat_' . $custom_term->slug;
      }
    }
  }
  return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'woo_custom_taxonomy_in_body_class' );
```

Basically, the end goal is to have certain products able to be added to cart and show prices and checkout, but to have those options and information hidden on the vast majority of the products and the website.
Thanks

Comment: I'm just going to wing it and say you need `body:not(.product_cat_Category1) .custom-single-product ...` etc. in your css rule set.

Comment: Check your generated HTML source to see if your category class is actually getting added to the body element.

Comment: Checked with inspector, CSS class is indeed being added to body tag.

Comment: Thanks @KodosJohnson Your first comment worked!

Comment: Great glad I could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `body:not(.product_cat_Category1)`  to each CSS rule. So it should look like this:

```
body:not(.product_cat_Category1) .custom-single-product .cart, body:not(.product_cat_Category1) span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount, body:not(.product_cat_Category1) a.cart-customlocation.et-cart-info {
    display: none !important;
}
```